# Why windows.onload is executed several times?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm binding the window.onload event like this

```
// It's a little more complex than this, I analyze if there is any other function 
// attached but for the sake of the question it's ok, this behaves the same.
window.onload = myfunction;
```

Onload is triggered twice on my local machine a several times on the production server

If I change it by the jQuery equivalent

```
$jQuery(window).load(myfunction);
```

It behaves as expected (executed only once).

Could you help me to understand possible reasons why the first option it's not working as supposed?

Thanks!

Comment: Given your edit, there is not enough context to guess at any possible reasons why the method would be called twice.  Please include any other references to load events and/or `myfunction`.

Comment: What you're showing here is completely standard. We need to see the rest of your code to see where the problem lies.

Comment: @Timmy: It seems you have "exampled" your problem away. Unless you modify your question with your *actual* code, there's no reason to keep this open.

Comment: myfunction contains whatever you want. I tested with just an alert. I can't paste here all the javascript of the project. I know my code is standard, but I'm asking for tools to troubleshoot, not the solution itself. I'm 100% positive that the problem is not on that specific code so that's why I'm not confusing everyone pasting that.

Comment: @Timmy: Have you tried stepping through your code with a debugger?

Comment: @Timmy it's not what `myfunction` contains.  You're right, that doesn't matter, but that's not what's been asked for. It's where/how it's used, assigned, called, referenced, etc. and same with *any* load event handlers.

Comment: @Jeremy Heiler : It's an event handler. It just get executed at browser's will :) I can put a breakpoint on myfunction but I don't know how would help. Thanks!

Comment: @Timmy a break point would help because you could see the call stack.

Comment: @Renesis: do you know how to see the stack on Crhome or IE? This is not happening on FF.

Comment: @Timmy: In Chrome you can go to `Wrench > Tools > Developer Tools` and click on the Scripts tab to add breakpoints and watch the stack.

Comment: @Timmy - updated my post to include a screenshot.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

<strike>The parentheses on your assignment — `myfunction()` — executes your function.  You haven't shown what `myfunction` does, but this means that the return value from that function is being assigned to `window.onload`, not the function itself.  So, I don't know how that is getting executed, unless you have somehow got that to work, like ending the function with `return this;`</strike>

You want

```
window.onload = myfunction;
```

---

Given the nature of `window.onload`, it seems unlikely that pure browser events alone are making *both* calls to `myfunction`.  Therefore, a breakpoint inside your function will help you see the call stack.  I've included screenshots for Chrome.

Sample code:

```
var alertme = function() {
    alert("Hello");
}

window.onload = alertme;

function testsecondcall() {
    alertme();
}

testsecondcall();
```

1. Open your page in Chrome.
2. After the page has loaded once, open the Developer Tools panel and put a breakpoint on the line inside your function, then refresh the page.
3. Check the call stack of *both* times that it breaks.  One will be empty (the actual window.onload).  The other should give you some information like the following:

[image]

**On the right, under "Call Stack", you see `alertme` is called by `testsecondcall`**

Comment: Man, beat me by 18 seconds. :-)

Comment: sorry, stupid mispelling error on the question. The code is correct, but I wrote it wrong here. I just fixed the question. Thanks