# Javascript functions being executed twice

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this next code which I am trying to print some data on screen.
The issue which I am facing is that each function is being executed twice so therefore the `console.log` appears on my console twice also.

It is really bizarre that this thing is happening.
My code goes like this:
I tried doing it with `window.onload` and also tried to import the functions inside the `document.ready`
but no luck.

If anyone can give me any hint what I am doing wrong, that would be really appreciating.

```
<body class="stretched">
    <div id="wrapper" class="clearfix">
        <!--Cargamos Layout de NavBar -->
        @Html.Partial("_NavBar_DataUser")
        <!--Fin de Carga -->
        <section id="carouselComercialTop" class="mt-auto">
            <div class="content-wrap">
                <!--Cargamos el caroussel stático -->
                @Html.Partial("_Layout_Caroussel")
            </div>

        </section>
        @Html.Partial("_Layout_Medicina360")

        <iframe class="pt-4" frameborder="0" width="100%" height="100%" src='#' name="zoom360" id="zoom360" style="display:none;"></iframe>
    </div>
    @Html.Partial("_Layout_DataUserFooter")
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/lib/slick-1.8.1/slick/slick.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/lib/slick-1.8.1/slick/slick-theme.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/lib/slick-1.8.1/slick/slick.css" />
</body>
    <script>
      window.ca_model = [];
      let stringJSONConsultaBuscador = ("@Context.Session.GetString("ConsultaBuscador")");
      window.ca_model = JSON.parse(stringJSONConsultaBuscador.replace(/&quot;/g, '"'));
      let especialistas = window.ca_model.listaEspecialistas;
      let especialista360varon = [];
      let especialista360mujer = [];
      let especialista360nino = [];
      let listaEspecialistas = window.ca_model.listaEspecialistas;
      let varon360 = listaEspecialistas.filter(b => b.hombres360 !== false);
      let mujer360 = listaEspecialistas.filter(b => b.mujeres360 !== false);
      let ninos360 = listaEspecialistas.filter(b => b.ninos360 !== false);

      especialista360varon.push(varon360);
      especialista360mujer.push(mujer360);
      especialista360nino.push(ninos360);

      especialista360varon = especialista360varon[0];
      especialista360mujer = especialista360mujer[0];
      especialista360nino = especialista360nino[0];

    function loadEspecialista360Varon(especialista360varon) {
        console.log(especialista360varon);
    }
    function loadEspecialista360Mujer(especialista360mujer) {
        console.log(especialista360mujer);
    }
    function loadEspecialista360Nino(especialista360nino) {
        console.log(especialista360nino);
    }

    window.onload = function () {
        loadEspecialista360Varon(especialista360varon);
        loadEspecialista360Mujer(especialista360mujer);
        loadEspecialista360Nino(especialista360nino);
    };
    $(document).ready(function () {
        let mobile = window.matchMedia('(max-width: 767px)').matches;
        let url = window.location.href;

        $('.link-carousel').each(function(){
            let href = $(this).attr("href");
            let container = $(this).parent().parent();
            if (url.indexOf(href) > -1){
                container.css({"background-color" : "rgb(173, 124, 177)"});
            }
        });

        let cuadroMedicoButton = document.getElementById("cuadroMedicoButton");
        cuadroMedicoButton.setAttribute("href", "/CuadroAsistencial/AsistenciaSpecialistas");
        if (mobile) {
            $('#mainRow').removeClass("d-flex");
            $('#mainCol').removeClass("d-flex");
            $('#containerMedicina360').replaceClass("py-5 py-2");
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Can you narrow down to the minimal code required to recreate the issue?  Maybe convert to a snippet with your data as a js variable (if it's needed to recreate) so we can see it working.

Comment: Does this help to diagnose the issue? https://stackoverflow.com/a/6219693/2181514

Comment: This seems a possibility: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10727036/2181514